# Laravel JWT Auth Token invalid / Signature could not be verified

Tags: laravel, jwt

I'm getting pretty tired of this error.. Stuck for 2 days now.

I do receive a token on valid credentials, but my token stays invalid, no matter if I pass it through url parameter (?token=[token]) or as Auth header (Bearer: [token]).
Anyone still experiencing this? I followed everything in the tutorial. Also configured both `.htaccess` in my public folder, and in my apache configuration.

```
Route::get('/test', function () {
  return JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();
});
```

Going to this route returns

TokenInvalidException in `NamshiAdapter.php` line 71:
Token Signature could not be verified.
For lookups, here is my authentication method from my AuthController.php

```
public function authenticate(Request $request) {
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

    $user = User::where('email', Input::get('email'))->first();

    try {
        if (!$token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
            return $this->respondUnauthorized();
        }
    } catch (JWTException $e) {
          return $this->respondInternalError('Could not create token!');
    }
    // dd()
    return $this->respond([
        'token' => compact('token'),
        'user' => $user]);
}
```

My routes middleware group:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['jwt.auth', 'jwt.refresh']], function() {
```

When I check line 71 in my NamshiAdapter and I dd() my token it says my secret is empty...

There must be something wrong? Is this just a minor bug or am I missing something?

Comment: you need to set the api secret in jwt.php inside the configuration folder... laravel will generate the token, but since the key is non existing it can not be verified and therefor the app do not know if it is a legal token

Comment: did you run `php artisan jwt:secret`?

Comment: Did both, also tried generating a key for jwt, doesnt set it automatically (which is another bug), setting it manually solves no problem.. @g3ek1337

Comment: out of curiosity which version of JWT are you using? because I had some similar issue and end up being `namshi/jose` version creating issues with another package and the token could not be verified.

Comment: Ehmm, I believe it's 0.5.9..? In my composer.json it says ">=0.5".. Where can I check the exact version? I tried updating it with composer update. @g3ek1337

Comment: I checked using composer show, it's 0.5.9, except, Namshi is 5.0.*, but packagist says it depends on Namshi V ^7.0?? https://packagist.org/packages/tymon/jwt-auth I'll guess I'll try and install Namshi 7.0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128608/discussion-between-fabian-tjoe-a-on-and-g3ek1337).

Comment: I had this same problem, Namshi version 5.0.*, and 7.0 is required. It would be helpful to know how you solved this problem. Your chat link leads to a 404 obviously.

Answer (score 2):

in Laravel 5.5 (in my case):

1- Run the command:

```
php artisan jwt:secret
```

you should see this result:

> jwt-auth secret [mygeneratedsecret] set successfully.

2- copy the secret, which is between the bracket (mygeneratedsecret) and add it to the .env file as following:

```
JWT_SECRET=mygeneratedsecret
```

3- Make sure your configuration file `jwt.php` has the secret set as following:

```
'secret' => env('JWT_SECRET'),
```

Important Note:

> Don't forget to Re-generate the Token (using your login script or whatever you use), because the old token (before the secret configuration)
>   will still be invalid against the new secret

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue

the solution is what jycr753 have said... "setting the api secret in jwt.php"

in fact on config/jwt.php, there is the line`'secret' => env('JWT_SECRET'),`,

- Generate the key with this helper `php artisan jwt:generate` (for some reason I dont know why it doesnt set in the .env file itself like `php artisan key:generate`).
- Copy the key (`jwt-auth secret [DSvO98YtJ0204mBu9zqWN9QOMX7Tmvr9] set successfully.`) without the bracket and add it in .env file like `JWT_SECRET=DSvO98YtJ0204mBu9zqWN9QOMX7Tmvr9` or you can change it straigth in jwt.php `secret' => env('DSvO98YtJ0204mBu9zqWN9QOMX7Tmvr9')`

Comment: the last line should be env('JWT_SECRET', 'DSvO98YtJ0204mBu9zqWN9QOMX7Tmvr9')

Comment: In the file config/jwt.php in the line where you have  `'secret' => env('JWT_SECRET')`, after generating the key with the command `php artisan jwt:generate` copy that key it might be different from mine and replace the JWT_SECRET in the jwt.php file

Comment: And make sure to regenerate the auth user token via the auth endpoint after generating a new JWT_SECRET